# How to open a cmd window and have it task kill a process by the process ID in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is what I have:

string processID = ID_numbers.Text;

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("taskkill /I {0} /F"), processID);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

and this is the error I keep getting:

System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'

Comment: I forgot to add this to the top: string processID = ID_numbers.Text;

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("taskkill /I {0} /F"), processID);
```

to

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("taskkill /I {0} /F", processID));
```

or I believe you can just do this:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("taskkill /I {0} /F", processID);
```

You were missing the argument in `string.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Intern("taskkill /IM {0} /F"), processID);